# get json data in android emualtor from pc

Tags: android, json, connection, ip, localhost

I have web API that runs on my pc "localhost" and I want to use this API
in android app to receive some json data. how can I get json data in android emulator when both asp nec core web API and nativescript android app are in  my pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `localhost` resolves to the address `127.0.0.1`. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) regarding emulators networking:

> Also note that the address 127.0.0.1 on your development machine corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface. If you want to access services running on your development machine loopback interface (a.k.a. 127.0.0.1 on your machine), you should use the special address 10.0.2.2 instead.

Now, in order to access the server from the emulator, the address should be like this: `http://10.0.2.2:xxxx`, where `xxxx` represent the port number.

Comment: i accepted but can't upwote because my reputation is low than 15